# Google Translate Api V2 C# with multiple phrases

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-translate

Can anyone show me an example of how to make multiple phrase translation with google translate api?

I am using the following now:

```
var service = new TranslateService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
           ApiKey = "my-key-here",
           ApplicationName = "something"
      });

string[] translatelist = new string[] { contentToTranslate, "en" };
var response = service.Translations.List(translatelist, "tr").ExecuteAsync();
string translatedtext = response.Result.Translations[0].TranslatedText;
```

I tried making translatelist 2 dimensional but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.